# Excel macro - pasting a selection into Word

Tags: excel, ms-word, copy-paste, vba

I'm using the code below

```
iMaxRow = 200

" Loop through columns and rows"
For iCol = 1 To 3 
For iRow = 1 To iMaxRow

With Worksheets("GreatIdea").Cells(iRow, iCol)
    " Check that cell is not empty."
    If .Value = "" Then
        "Nothing in this cell."
        "Do nothing."
    Else
        " Copy the cell to the destination"
        .Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, iCol)
    End If
End With

Next iRow
Next iCol
```

The code above is only applicable on the same excel sheet. I would like to extend it so it pastes into a word document. I presume it's something with;

```
appWD.Selection.PasteSpecial
```

But the problem is, I haven't made any selections. The code is good, just `Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, iCol)` needs to be edited.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If anyone is looking for further information, just have a look here : http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=81

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iMaxRow = 200 ' or whatever the max is.
'Don't make too large because this will slow down your code.

' Loop through columns and rows
For iCol = 1 To 3 ' or however many columns you have
    For iRow = 1 To iMaxRow

    With Worksheets("GreatIdea").Cells(iRow, iCol)
        ' Check that cell is not empty.
        If .Value = "" Then
            'Nothing in this cell.
            'Do nothing.
        Else
            ' Copy the cell to the destination
            .Copy
            appWD.Selection.PasteSpecial
        End If
    End With

    Next iRow
Next iCol
```